# Trying to convert string to a value

Tags: c#

I have a class

```
class Names{
    public static string One = "Value of One";
};
```

And I have a method

```
void GetValue(string strValue)
{
    string strDef = "Names." + strValue;
    //Now here i want to get the value of Names.One if the value of strValue is "One"
    //I want to get the value of Names.One in a variable
    strResult = ??;//what to do here
    //so that the contents of strResult will be "Value of One"
}
```

and I call GetValue like this

```
GetValue("One");
```

I don't want to use if else or dictionary. I want to to know is it possible to do it in this way?

I tried reflection like this but it always returns null also I have a static property in the class so I am not creating an object

```
 PropertyInfo pinfo = typeof(Names).GetProperty("One");
 object value = pinfo.GetValue(null, null);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to turn a string to a property name?

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<int, string>`.

Comment: yes..and i want the value of the property

Comment: Your post is confusing.  Are you trying to evaluate a `Names` type or compare if some string matches the value of `Names.One`?

Comment: Are you looking for [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx)?

Comment: your approach is understandable but inappropriate. Look into `Dictionary` class to achive that functionality.

Comment: apart from using dictionary is it possible to do it any other way?

Comment: Yeah, working with reflection would do it, but it is a way too much expensive job for a task like this.

Comment: yes can it be done using reflection..if so how?

Comment: @singh see the answer I provided

Comment: @singh - Why would you insist on doing it in another way than using a dictionary? Give us a good reason for it, and we can try and come up with a good approach to solve your problem. I don't think your solution is a static class that is used solely to store string values.

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen : actually i wanted to #define strings like we can do it in c but i couldn't find a way to do so in c# and ended like this.I have many many string that i have to #define

Comment: @singh - When working in another language, the best approach it not necessarily the solution that you used to solve it in some other language ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I dont want to use if else or dictionary

Then use reflection:

```
public static object GetValue(string propertyName)
{
    var property = typeof(Names).GetField(propertyName);
    return property.GetValue(null);
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string res = GetValue("One") as string;   // "Value of One"

    Console.Read();
}
```

But **do consider using the dictionary approach** (see answer of Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen) that is much more efficient.

Comment: your solution worked for me...but why is everyone emphasizing on use of dictionary over Reflection..can you just brief me

Comment: @singh Well, reflection requires way more CPU usage than a dictionary. Also, it is less readable for someone else than see/work with your code. And also a lot less maintainable.

Comment: @singh: reflection is slow and error-prone since it relies on the implementation which is not guaranteed. So it might change in future, but your code will not recognize it at compile time. You don't have compile-time safety in general which is dangerous. It also causes your code to be less maintainable and readable.

Comment: ok thanks..i am accepting you answer as it solved my case..but will use dictionary

Answer (score 9):

You can do this using reflection, but I would suggest changing your Names class to a Dictionary instead.

Then you can add elements to the `Dictionary` like this

```
names.Add("One", "Value of one");
```

And then your `GetValue` methos will be really simple

```
void GetValue(string strValue)
{
  if( names.ContainsKey(strValue))
  {
    return names[strValue];
  }
  return "Not found";
}
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Whoops, I falsely remembered that Dictionary had that method in C#. Updated my code now.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - HasKey, [ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) - whichever works. ^_^

Comment: i got the result using reflection but y shouldn't i use reflection but use dictionary instead?

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen: Use [`Names.ContainsKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx) otherwise you have an  O(n) operation instead of an an efficient O(1) operation.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `Dictionary<int, string>` instead of using [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
public class Names
{
    private static Dictionary<int, string> Values = null;

    static Names()
    {
        Values = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        Values.Add(1, "Value of One");
        Values.Add(2, "Value of Two");
        // ...
    }

    public static string GetValue(int key)
    {
        string value;
        Values.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in the following way:

```
string valueOfOne = Names.GetValue(1);
```

Of course you can also use a `string` as key, but i assume that you have used `"One"` only because the code didn't compile with an `int` as variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Completely disregarding the fact why you'd like to do this and if there are better ways to achieve what you want to do (there are!), you could change the public value to a static property like

```
class Names 
{
    public static string One
    {
        get
        {
            return "Value of One";
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your GetValue method you can access the property via reflection

```
void GetValue(string name)
{
    ...
    foreach(PropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeof(Names).GetProperties())
    {
        if(propertyInfo.Name == name &&
           propertyInfo.CanRead)
        {
            strResult = propertyInfo.GetValue(null, null);
            return;
        }
    }
    //throw an excetion when the name does not exist
    throw new ArgumentExcetion(string.Format("There is no name \"{0}\"",name)); 
}
```

Anyway, I am osting this just for sake of completeness, for I think using dictionaries is really a better way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is using Resources, you could add a resource named Names to your project and then access the stored strings pretty much like in your example via

```
Names.One
Names.Two
Names.Fred
```

But then with Resources you may also use the ResourceManager class in your GetValue method

```
ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager("YourNamespace.Names", typeof(Names).Assembly);
...
strResult = resourceManager.GetString(name);
```

Please note, that you'll have to test if the result is null, i.e. no string with the name has been found.

Comment: does using resource manager have any performance issues over using a dictionary?

Comment: First of all: What the heck are you trying to do, that performance matters that much to you that you are willingly making your life as hard as possible. Dictionaries would be perfect for your case as far as you described it. Anyway, I'd guess that ResourceManager would use reflection, which would make him slower than a Dictionary I think.